# Is there a way to prevent this race condition with GDScript Dictionaries?

Tags: dictionary, sprite, race-condition, godot, gdscript

I am working with the following function in GDScript:

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    sprite_lst[ent].queue_free()
    sprite_lst.erase(ent)
    draw_entities()
```

`sprite_lst` is a Dictionary that holds all of the Sprites on the HUD. The keys for these Sprites are the actual object that they're representing. This function is called to remove one of those sprites from the HUD.

This mostly works alright, however, it seems to have a race condition preventing it from always working as intended. Sometimes, this function will throw an exception when trying to call `queue_free()` on the intended object, because `ent` is not found as a key in `sprite_lst`.

To troubleshoot, I tried printing out the object ID before erasing it. However, once I added a `print` statement to this function, it stopped throwing the exception. So then I changed the function to this:

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    var this_sprite = sprite_lst[ent]
    this_sprite.queue_free()
    sprite_lst.erase(ent)
    draw_entities()
```

When storing the entity from `sprite_lst`, the function always works. It seems to me like sometimes the `erase()` method is called on the dictionary, before `queue_free()` is called on the Sprite.

Is there any way to prevent this race condition, or force these two lines to run sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to me like sometimes the `erase()` method is called on the dictionary, before `queue_free()` is called on the Sprite.

In your code, you always call `queue_free()` first. However, that queues a free. It is similar to `call_deferred("free")` (not exactly the same, but this gets the idea across).

---

We can apply plenty of defensive programming to your code.

First of all, we can check if the entry is there:

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    if sprite_lst.has(ent):
        # …
        pass
```

Or we can use `get` which will return null if it isn't:

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    var this_sprite = sprite_lst.get(ent)
    # …
```

Second we can check if we got a valid instance (not null and not freed):

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    var this_sprite = sprite_lst.get(ent)
    if is_instance_valid(this_sprite):
        this_sprite.queue_free()

    # …
```

That way there should be no exception on the `queue_free` call.

I suppose you want to remove any invalid entry, too, right? Thankfully `erase` won't complain about a key not being there, so we don't need a check to guard it.

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    var this_sprite = sprite_lst.get(ent)
    if is_instance_valid(this_sprite):
        this_sprite.queue_free()

    sprite_lst.erase(ent)
    draw_entities()
```

---

Alright, that takes care of the error. However, why do you care about when the node gets freed? I'll venture to guess that the reason you care is because you rely on it to remove the node from the scene tree. We could address that directly:

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    var this_sprite:Node = sprite_lst.get(ent)
    if is_instance_valid(this_sprite):
        if this_sprite.is_inside_tree():
            this_sprite.get_parent().remove_child(this_sprite)

        this_sprite.queue_free()

    sprite_lst.erase(ent)
    draw_entities()
```

I suppose you could do this instead (which isn't the same, because this also works outside of the scene tree, but I don't think we need to worry about that case):

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    var this_sprite:Node = sprite_lst.get(ent)
    if is_instance_valid(this_sprite):
        var parent:Node = this_sprite.get_parent()
        if parent != null:
            parent.remove_child(this_sprite)

        this_sprite.queue_free()

    sprite_lst.erase(ent)
    draw_entities()
```

On that note, be aware that attempting to remove a `Node` from another `Node` which isn't the parent will cause an error. So even if you know which should be parent, you still need a check:

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    var this_sprite:Node = sprite_lst.get(ent)
    if is_instance_valid(this_sprite):
        if parent == this_sprite.get_parent():
            parent.remove_child(this_sprite)

        this_sprite.queue_free()

    sprite_lst.erase(ent)
    draw_entities()
```

Or, if it works for you, you could avoid parent shenanigans with `remove_and_skip`, for example:

```
func remove_entity(ent: Sprite):
    var this_sprite:Node = sprite_lst.get(ent)
    if is_instance_valid(this_sprite):
        if this_sprite.is_inside_tree():
            this_sprite.remove_and_skip()

        this_sprite.queue_free()

    sprite_lst.erase(ent)
    draw_entities()
```

Be aware that `remove_and_skip` will add the children of the node back to the scene tree. While `remove_child` would not (the `Node` will keep children outside the scene tree).

---

For completeness I'll also mention that:

- `erase` returns whether or not it removed something.
- You can use `is_queued_for_deletion` to check if you called `queue_free` on an `Object`.

And also remind you that freeing a `Node` does not make all the reference to it `null`, instead they become invalid, which is why `is_instance_valid` and checking if it isn't `null` aren't the same thing.